# Trying to join two mp4 video files using ffmpeg but getting error

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to join two mp4 video files, but I'm getting following error:

**Unable to find a suitable output format for 'ffmpeg'.**

**ffmpeg: Invalid argument**

My code is below:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "path to ffmpeg";
startInfo.Arguments = "ffmpeg -f concat -i "+path_to_text_file+" -c copy "+path_to_output_video;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        try
        {
            Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);
            while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Process Standard Output : " + process.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

My input text file is like

```
file '/path/to/input0'
file '/path/to/input1'
```

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing i can see is that you're using "ffmpeg " as part of your argument. This would be for calling the executable. But you already do that when defining the target FileName. So the final command looks kinda like this:

"\ffmpeg ffmpeg -f concat -i ...."

So if you remove the "ffmpeg" part from your argument and try again :-)

Comment: I just removed the ffmpeg part and it worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please mark this as an answer if it worked for you :-)